# ACF Nested Group field get parameters

Tags: wordpress, nested, advanced-custom-fields

I've tried different variants with nested groups, but still can't make it work. This is what I have:
        Group (group)
           -- Group title(text)
           -- Subgroup(group)
           ---**Subgroup title(text)
           ---**Subgroup text(textarea)
I can get the Group title only. Not the Subgroup. My code:

```
<div class="test">
            <?php
                $group = get_field('group');
                echo $group['group_title'];
                if( get_field($group) ):
                    if(get_sub_field('sub_group')):
                        echo the_sub_field('sub_group_title');        
                        echo the_sub_field('sub_group_text');
                    endif;
                endif;

            ?>
</div>
```

Do I need to use an array here to get the fields for sub_group_title and sub_group_text?
**UPDATED:**

```
<div class="test">
<?php
    if( have_rows('group') ):
      while( have_rows('group') ): the_row();
        $group_title = get_sub_field('group_title');
        $sub_group = get_sub_field('sub_group');
      endwhile;
    endif;
    echo '<p>' . $group_title . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $sub_group['sub_group_title'] . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $sub_group['sub_group_text'] . '</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the while before print sub_fields

```
while( have_rows('group') ): the_row(); 
   echo the_sub_field('sub_group_title');        
endwhile;
```

Here you need to change if( get_field($group) ): to  if($group): as u already assigned that in $group = get_field('group');

More example here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/

Hope thats help!

Comment: Thanks Mohammed! After reading carefully and playing with code, it worked! The working code is added above. Will also try to play with 3d level group later.

Comment: No problem Natalya :)